# How to change give highest priority to Mail traffic on port 25 with tc

Tags: linux, traffic-shaping, tc

How can I give the highest priority to mail traffic on port 25 whit tc?

I tried `prio` option but It didn't work out for me or maybe I'm missing something.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: It would be useful to show us  exactly what you've tried and say why that's not doing what you expect/want.

Comment: Thanks for your help: I use this command: `tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 10: prio 1 u32 match ip dport 22`

Comment: Answer to similar problem provided: https://serverfault.com/a/352035/420553